# How to get highest difference from atable

Tags: sql, oracle

I have following table(currency):

```
___________________________
|symbol|rate   |Date      |
---------------------------
|USD   |1.23   |2014-09-08|
|JPY   |136.27 |2014-09-08|
|BGN   |1.9558 |2014-09-08|
|USD   |1.22   |2014-09-07|
|JPY   |136.23 |2014-09-07|
|BGN   |1.9551 |2014-09-07|
```

Something like that. How can I get the highest currency rate difference (max(rate)-min(rate)). I come up with something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT c.symbol, MAX(c.rate) - MIN(c.rate) AS diff
   FROM Currency c 
   GROUP BY c.symbol
   ORDER BY diff DESC)
WHERE ROWNUM=1;
```

Above query produce the currency with the highest change rate. It returns the first row which is sorted. But I also need to list even if there two or more currency that has same change rate as the highest currency.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in several ways.  Here is a way that uses `rank()`:

```
SELECT c.*
FROM (SELECT c.symbol, MAX(c.rate) - MIN(c.rate) AS diff,
             rank() over (order by MAX(c.rate) - MIN(c.rate) DESC) as seqnum
      FROM Currency c 
      GROUP BY c.symbol
     ) c
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```